# Run Javascript from php file after runtime

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, variables

Okay, so the idea is that I need a piece of javascript to run once an if statement in php has been met however this needs interaction with the dom, so assume a button being pressed and a variable has been passed to the php on button press. (It isn't that senario but fairly similar):

```
if ($button == 1){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> document.getElementById("myForm").submit(); </script>';
}
```

And I want once this condition is met for this code to run. It needs to be within the php if statement I can't move it to js. However I did think about trying to add the code into a variable and passing that variable to the js via ajax but didn't work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.   PHP runs on the **server**.  You need AJAX polling or WebSockets.

Comment: Is'nt it kind of an oxymoron to have a PHP condition relying on the DOM (not counting ajax etc) ??

Comment: Why don't you just use JavaScript to see if the button has been pressed?

Answer (score 1):

do you mean just wanting to run a piece of javascript, after a php condition is met? If so:

*myScript.php*

```
<?php
    $button = 1;
    if ($button == 1){
      echo "submit form";
    }
?>
```

*myScript.js*

```
$.ajax({
  type:"POST"
  url:"myScript.php"
  success: function(data){
    if(data == "submit form"){
      //submits "myForm"
      $("#myForm").submit();
    }
  }
});
```

as said by *SLaks*, its not possible to execute javascript in php, because php runs on the server, and javascript runs on the client. to make it easier to understand: they are basically 2 seperate "worlds" which can only run certain code.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, however with your code I am getting a error message of "missing function declaration" and "unexpected identifier".

Comment: hmm, gimme a sec and ill test it out on my server. by the way, what i posted isn't enough code to work by itself

Comment: nah, he means putting the ajax call in a function. but he hasn't specified what calls the function, so ill just take a random guess hah